# Transfer multidomain PHP application to AWS Autoscaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, php, asg

We have a bunch of websites (>15) running on the same codebase. Currently our strategy is to run every website on a separate Lightsail/EC2 instance. Website behavior depends on .env file but it is possible to change this dependency to hostname. We have a lot of git changes every day. We keep instances state in sync via Deployer (Gitlab CI/CD). Due to our strategy (one website - one VPS) it is costly to scale such infrastructure.

There is a single master instance for admin & content editing purposes with write access to RDS database. Other instances are used for website domains and they have read access to RDS DB I mentioned before. We also have S3 for product gallery.

It seems it would be pretty standard to migrate such infrastructure to AWS ASG but there are some bottlenecks:

- every website has local MySQL DB (storing orders, cart, user uploaded images, queue, etc.)
- every website has several supervisor workers
- every website has own local files (such as logs, user uploaded images)
- every website has own Redis Storage

How could we move this infrastructure to AWS ASG/ALB to reduce costs?

*I've checked [Where to start? Scaling PHP applications on AWS](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/where-to-start-scaling-php-applications-on-aws) answer but I couldn't figure out how to handle these bottlenecks.*